Getting “document stream not found” error response in postman
I created below request in postman
{
  "CheckInDoc": {
    "cabinetName": "abcd",
    "userDBId": "1244",
    "checkInOutFlag": "N",
    "curtentDateTime":"",
    "majorVersion":"",
    "documentIndex": "321",
    "limitCount": "1000",
    "createdByAppName": "pdf",
    "documentName" : "abc",
    "versionComment": "",
    "supAnnotVersion": "N",
    "yolumeld": "1",
    "locale": "en_US"
  }
}

When I am trying to checkin this document it is giving below error in response -

Document path/stream not found

How can this be fixed?
I am expecting success message like “document checked in successfully”
